# Calculate frequency of a attribute field per polygon

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have spatially joined a polygon file with census tracts of areas in Houston with a theft occurrence point shapefile. The attribute table contains a field that represents different classes of theft (ie. Class A: $0-$1000, Class B: $1001 -$2000 etc). I want to calculate the frequency of classes in each of my census tracts. So in essence how many different theft classes occur in each of the census tracts. I have figured out how to get the count, but this is not what I want. How would I go about obtaining and representing the frequency?

Answer (score 3):

To do this use [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) with a Case Field:

> • A field will be created for each statistic type using the following
>   naming convention: SUM_, MAX_, MIN_,
>   RANGE_, STD_, FIRST_, LAST_, COUNT_
>   (where  is the name of the input field for which the statistic
>   is computed). The field name is truncated to 10 characters when the
>   output table is a dBASE table.
>
> • If a Case field is specified, statistics will be calculated
>   separately for each unique attribute value. The Output Table will
>   contain only one record if no Case field is specified. If one is
>   specified, there will be one record for each Case field value.

I have assumed that when you say "I have figured out how to get the count" you mean how to use the Get Count tool.  In the above COUNT_ should be the frequency of each class that you are looking for instead.

Comment: Export joined table to excel

Answer (score -2):

Export joined table to excel. Pivot table will do the rest, using polygon Id as row headers. Based on my experience it is the fastest way to accomplish you task. Managing pivot tables is much easier in Excel compare to ArcGIS