# Counting number of instances of certain field value using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, runtimeerror, attributeerror

I am creating code that accesses a shapefile named Schools.shp. I data I am trying to locate is the attribute field named FACILITIES. Within the FACILITIES field I am trying to get values that the field contains named HIGH SCHOOLS. In my code I need count the number of high schools I found. The value High School needs to be accessed through user input. (raw_input statement).

Using arcpy.da formatting.

```
import arcpy

work = "c:\Scripts\Lab 6 Data"
facility = "High School"
whereClause = "\"FACILITY\" = 'HIGH SCHOOL' "
shapefile = "Schools.shp"
arcpy.env.workspace = work
field = ['FACILITY']

searchCurs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, field, whereClause)
row = searchCurs.next()
for row in searchCurs:
    # using getValue() to get the name of the high school
    value = row.getValue("NAME")
    row = searchCurs.next()
    #count the number of specific facilities   
    result = row.GetCount_management("NAME")
    count = int(result.getOutput(0))
    print (count)
```

My issue is setting up the code so that the user can enter various facility types and the correct count for each facility is returned. Ex: User inputs High School, 29 is returned..... User inputs Junior High, 6 is returned.

Comment: Use Add Field Delimiters tool for your sql clause to rule out errors with " or ' signs

Comment: You've got several significant errors in this Python code.  DA cursor rows do not support getValue, so you never got to the GetCount_management error.

Comment: @Vince Is AddField the arcpy.da equivalent to getValue?

Comment: value = row[0] is the equivalent of getValue. row[0] is the first field in the cursor, row[1] would be the second if you included more fields, and so on.

Comment: @phloem My updated error is that it prints out the number of high schools(29x). Is there a way to print it just once?

Comment: It would be best to roll back the edits to include your original question and the screenshot, then add edits to that if necessary.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us not just some code, but also the precise error message, including line number, that you get when you run the exact code that you present.  See http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312 for tips.

Comment: I think that there is a far easier way to accomplish this which is to use Summary Statistics with a case field - see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/144887/115

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
import arcpy
try:
    work = "c:\Scripts\Lab 6 Data"
    facility = "High School"
    whereClause = "\"FACILITY\" = 'HIGH SCHOOL' "
    shapefile = "Schools.shp"
    arcpy.env.workspace = work
    field = ['FACILITY']

    searchCurs = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, field, whereClause)
    row = searchCurs.next()
    for row in searchCurs:
    # using getValue() to get the name of the high school
    value = row[0]
    high_schools = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, field, whereClause)]
    count = len(high_schools)
    print count
```

I've altered the getValue methods towards a method more acceptable towards arcpy.da "row[0]"

I have also got the count of high schools using. Though this result prints out 29x. It is acceptable because i have not found a way for it to print once.

```
high_schools = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shapefile, field, whereClause)]
    count = len(high_schools)
```

Comment: Is this a solution or additional info for your question?  If it's your solution please [edit] to include a bit of a description around what you've done.  If it's additional info then please edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap a data access `da` [Search Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/searchcursor.htm) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Try the following:

```
import arcpy

shp = r'C:\path\to\your\shapefile.shp'

facility_count = len([row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "FACILITY") if "HIGH SCHOOL" in row[0]])
print facility_count
```

Alternatively, you can count all the items in a field using the [collections](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) module...

```
import arcpy
from collections import Counter

facility = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shp, "FACILITY")]

print Counter(facility)
```

Which yields something like...

```
Counter({u'HIGH SCHOOL': 4, u'MIDDLE SCHOOL': 1, u'ELEMENTARY SCHOOL': 1})
```

Comment: I get this error still RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.

Comment: The High schools are not a field name but a sub value of the Facility field

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the clarification. I will update my answer with the necessary changes.

Comment: Are you querying two fields, first the "FACILITIES" field, which contains a value of interest called "HIgh School" and then another field with the name of the facility?

Comment: Just one field named FACILITIES with the value of interest being the number of high schools in that field

Comment: @A_Worthy please edit your question to include this information about your fields and values

Comment: Does the FACILITY field have numeric or text values?

Comment: text: Facility types: Elementary, Middle, and High School

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your attribute table highlighting the FACILITY field? It is important to see exactly how the text is expressed.