# Debugging function takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)?

Tags: python

Create a function called "numSchools" that counts the schools of a specific type.
The function should have three input parameters, (1) a string for the workspace, (2) a string for the shapefile name, and (3) a string for the facility type (e.g. "HIGH SCHOOL"), and one output parameter, (1) an integer for the number of schools of that facility type in the shapefile.

```
import arcpy

shapefile = "Schools.shp"
work = r"c:\Scripts\Lab 6 Data"
sTyp = "HIGH SCHOOL"

def numSchools(work, shapefile, sTyp):

    whereClause = "\"FACILITY\" = 'HIGH SCHOOL' " # where clause for high schools
    field = ['FACILITY']
    searchCurs = arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile, field, whereClause)
    row = searchCurs.next()
    for row in searchCurs:
        # using getValue() to get the name of the high school
        value = row.getValue("NAME")

        high_schools = [row[0] for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(shapefile, field, whereClause)]
        count = arcpy.GetCount_management(high_schools)
        return count

numSchools("There are a total of: "),count
```

My error message states "  line 21, in 
TypeError: numSchools() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)"
This error is for the final line of my code.

My code is only supposed to output the number of high schools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting number of instances of certain field value using ArcPy?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226404/counting-number-of-instances-of-certain-field-value-using-arcpy)

Comment: What school are you at where you're learning this?

Comment: Please take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.

Comment: @DPSSpatial grad school programming with no prior programming experience necessary smh.

Comment: @A_Worthy no worries on your part, just wondering what school it is... Thanks!

Comment: To learn about writing Python functions I recommend using [so].  ArcPy cursors, ArcGIS Geoprocessing functions, etc are on-topic for [gis.se] Stack Exchange but this one is really pure Python.

Comment: I've rolled back your question to the version that the answer applies to.  What you had changed it to would mean the answer making no sense.  Edits to your questions should always try not to invalidate any answers.

Comment: @PolyGeo is it posssible to delete my question in order to ask it in the way its meant to be?

Comment: While it is possible in exceptional circumstances I see no justification for doing that. Just ask a new question but before doing that please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/q/41947632/820534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numSchools` function expects three parameters (`work`, `shapefile`, `sTyp`) to be supplied.

When you call it using:

```
numSchools("There are a total of: "),count
```

you are only providing one parameter value i.e. the string `"There are a total of: "`

The above is why Python reports:

> numSchools() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

---

Your error is pure Python and nothing to do with ArcPy, which you can see by running:

```
def numSchools(work, shapefile, sTyp):
    print work

numSchools("There are a total of: ")
```

to get an error of:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Temp\test.py", line 4,
>   in 
>       numSchools("There are a total of: ") TypeError: numSchools() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your last line be something such as:

```
print("There are a total of: " + str(numSchools(work, shapefile, sTyp)))
```

Comment: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1179, in SearchCursor
    return gp.searchCursor(dataset, where_clause, spatial_reference, fields, sort_fields)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 359, in searchCursor
    self._gp.SearchCursor(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.

Comment: my error message

Comment: I'm usually on the .NET side of things so ArcPy may be a bit different. The only thing that jumps out at me is that field names in .NET are not in quotes. In other words the WHERE clause in .NET would be "FACILITY = 'HIGH SCHOOL'".